# Web.config: Is it possible to use the value of a variable within the we.config file?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Imaging that I have defined the following connection string in my web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyConnName" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MY_LOCAL_DB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and then I would like to use that connection in one of my appSetting keys, for example:

```
<add key="MyAppKey.ConnectionString" value="MyConnName"/>
```

is that possible?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why would you define this in your app.Config if your connectionstring is already present in your web.config?

Comment: I am using a library "FeatureToggle" which uses the key to define the connection string.  
    <add key="FeatureToggle.MyFeautureToggle.ConnectionString" value="........"
This is a requirement from that library and I cannot reuse my connection string and I was looking for an option to reuse it

Comment: Well, you can do same thing when you use that app key in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For those who read the original question, this is what I have found:

- I could not find the exact solution I was looking.
- For those who use the **FeatureToggle** library: Looking at the code, I have found that you can set the connection string (when using SqlFeatureToggle class) in two different ways:

  - 1st option:

    > add key="FeatureToggle.MyFeautureToggle.ConnectionString" value="........"
  - 2nd option:  The 2nd option solved my original problem.

    > add key="FeatureToggle.MyFeautureToggle.ConnectionStringName" value="MyConnName"